# How to stop a method with a method inside it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Basically, I want to break the method if it's on cooldown. But when I move the if statement inside a method, it will not work. The return keyword will just return to the previous method and continue the rest.
Is there any way to do it?

[image]

Comment: What if `CooldownCheck` returned a `bool`?

Comment: Please post the code as text, not as image! So that we can copy paste to suggest changes or to test in VS.

Comment: Please [do not upload images of your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/10601203). The best course of action from the look of things would be to have `CooldownCheck` return a bool and have `Interact` return if it returns `true`. Another option would be to have it throw an exception then catch it farther up.

Comment: To be clear - you want to exit the calling method (Interact) if the the cooldown time did not expire?

Comment: alright, sorry I'm quite new to programming & this website.
Yup, I just want to wrap the method out of the main method.Already answered by Olivier with bool method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let the `CooldownCheck` method return the stop status, e.g., through a Boolean:

```cs
public void Interact()
{
    if (CooldownCheck()) {
        InInteract.Invoke();
        lastCooled = Time.time + cooldown;
    }
}

private bool CooldownCheck()
{
    if (lastCooled <= Time.time) {
        Debug.Log(stuff);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Btw., your `else { return; }` makes no sense, as any void method has an implicit `return;` at its end. The return-statement does not stop anything, it returns from the method, i.e., it leaves the method at this point and continues to run the caller, i.e., the caller will then execute the next statement.

A way to interrupt the caller would be to throw an exception. But this seems not appropriate in this case.

Comment: Yeah exceptions should be used when actually something is badly wrong ... The `bool` should be **the** way to go in this case